# tagging a javascript file within html script tag successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a html file that i am hosting on my local computer using nodemon (like an advanced node.js server).

within that html file I have some jQuery/js embedded in a script tag, and my code works that way.

but when I separate the jQuery/js code, and put it in a separate file called main.js it does not work.

I have tried linking it within the main.js
and ./main.js but none of them return my request.

can someone please suggest possible solutions I could be overlooking?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /*const url1 = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=';
  const url2 = '&symbol=';
  const url3 = '&outputsize=';
  const url4 = '&apikey=';
  const apiKey = 'RO6QHBGM0A4VO7NT';
  const fn = TIME_SERIES_DAILY;
  const outputsize= compact;
  const symbol = MSFT;
  */

  alert("hey");
  

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>SP</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Vicks StocPort</h1>
  <script src=
  'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
  <script src='./main.js'/>
  <script>
  const urlToFetch = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo';
  function getData(){
    //const urlToFetch = url1+fu+url2+symbol+url3+outputsize+url4+key;

    $.ajax({
        url: urlToFetch,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success(response){
          console.log(response);
          console.log('success from here');
        },
        error(jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
          console.log(jqXHR);
          console.log("error from here");
        }
    });
  }
  getData();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you put it in it's own file you need to make sure the new file is below the script call for jquery and main.js. if you put it above jquery you're going to get an error in the coneols saying "$ is undefined"... also, when you ask questions like this please post the error you got in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
<script src='./main.js'/>
  <script>
```

The `/` character on opening script tag

There are some tags that can be self closing tags, but `<script>` isn't one of them.

...and by the way... there's a simple reference listing all the tag you can use as self closing tags:
http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html

Comment: Just let me know if was only because of that typo. I hope it worked! Anyways I'd appreciate a upvote ☺️ thanks